# logic behing programing a diferential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a problem where I have:

$$ax + by + cz = k$$
$$ax' + by' + cz' = k'$$
$$ax'' + by'' + cz'' = k''$$

where

- `a`, `b` and `c` have resp the same value in all cases
- `x`, `y`, `z` and `k` are given values (also the `'` and `''` variants)
- all numbers are positive integers.

A example would be:

$$a * 2 + b*6 + c*9 = 75$$
$$a*5 + b*7 + c*2 = 53$$
$$a*6 + b*11 + c*13 = 127$$

and result would be: `a = 3`, `b = 4` and `c = 5`.

I'm trying to create a recursive program (in JavaScript programing language) to get the values of `a`, `b`, `c`.

I tried making every line `= 0` by passing the constant to the other side and then I get:

$$a(x - x' - x'') - b(y - y' - y'') - c(z - z' - z'') - k + k' + k'' = 0$$

and then test values inside a program with a loop and compare values between them. This gives big orders of magnitude when I generate loops to "brute force" test numbers and feels wrong.

How can I find a relation to solve these equations sharing the same `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: @Moo oh, no, sorry not so familiar with markdown. Its `a times 2`, etc... will try to fix

Comment: @Moo I know x, y, and z. But not the value of a, b and c. Sorry if the writing is not in mathematical expected logic.

Comment: @Moo _Gaussian Elimination_: no. Matrices I remember studying them in university like 20 years ago... :/ But I'm eager to learn them back. Can go and do some research in that direction again.

Comment: You can write in matrix notation as $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 6 & 9 \\ 5 & 7 & 2 \\ 6 & 11 & 13\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 75 \\ 53 \\ 127\end{pmatrix}$. You can then solve using matrix inverse or even better is Gaussian Elimination: http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/gauss/gauss.html. Also search for GE calculator with steps.

Comment: @Moo nice, will study that. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure you can find Java Script code for GE or even better to learn is Python - which has some awesome math stuff in SymPy.

Comment: @Moo that link was really usefull. Will make a matrice logic in JS (not so good in python unfortunatly) and reply back. Thanks again.